# How to center spinner menu programmatically?

Tags: android, menu, popup, spinner, center

I have activity in which I create spinner programmatically, spinner is opened by clicking on button, but each time I click on button spinner popup menu is in corner of the screen and not in middle and I need to show this spinner popup menu in the middle of screen.

Here is my code

```
Spinner s1 = new Spinner(this);
String[] test = { "Never", "3", "6" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, test);
        s1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        s1.setLayoutParams(params);

b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View paramView) {
                s1.performClick();
            }
        });
```

Comment: One simple solution would be to specify the position of spinner in your layout and link that view to your spinner. Is it essential in your app to not define a spinner in the layout ?

Comment: As I said I don't have spinner in my layout, coz I create it only programmatically, check this line:
Spinner s1 = new Spinner(this);

Answer (score 6):

After a lot of time and effort directed in the wrong direction am amused that the solution is very simple. Change the following

```
    Spinner s1 = new Spinner(this);
```

to

```
    Spinner s1 = new Spinner(this, Spinner.MODE_DIALOG);
```

By default it is `Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN`.

Comment: Thank you, it works, but problem is, that it is only for API 11 and higher and I need it for API 7 and higher.

Comment: Oh, if only you had mentioned that in the question, as I spent an entire day working on this one.

Comment: I believe that there must be some solution also for API lower than 11.

Comment: Will try to come up with a solution for that as well . BTW thanks for the upvote :)

Comment: How about using a custom spinner ?